# Top sales performer is in each month for a specified year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using the adventure works 2017 test database I need to see who the top sales performer is in each month for a specified year. The management is only interested in the sales of bike “Components”. Create a stored procedure to get this information.

1. The year must be an input parameter.
2. Show the firstname and surname in one field.
3. Show the total value of the sales and the month for each top performer.
4. Additional marks will be allocated for using a single statement

So far I have this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getTopSalesByYear (@Year int)
AS
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT  FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS SalesPerson,
    sp.BusinessEntityID,
    DATENAME(MONTH,SOH.OrderDate) as SalesMonth,
    SUM(SOH.SubTotal) AS TotalSales FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
INNER JOIN sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD ON SOH.SalesOrderId = SOD.SalesOrderId
INNER JOIN sales.SalesPerson sp on soh.SalesPersonID = sp.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Person.Person p on p.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Production.Product Pr on sod.ProductID = pr.ProductID
INNER JOIN Production.ProductCategory pc on pc.ProductCategoryID = pr.ProductSubcategoryID
INNER JOIN Production.ProductSubcategory psc on pc.ProductCategoryID = pc.ProductcategoryID
WHERE psc.ProductCategoryID = 2
GROUP BY p.FirstName,p.LastName,sp.BusinessEntityID, DATENAME(MONTH,SOH.OrderDate)
ORDER BY TotalSales desc
```

This is what I have so far but it needs to be a procedure with the year being passed. Also noting that I do not know where to pass the parameter to what value.

Comment: Your joining of Product, Category and SubCategory look wrong. AIUI it's `Product.SubCat -> SubCat.SubCat, SubCat.Cat -> Cat.Cat`

Comment: *"Also noting that I do not know where to pass the parameter to what value."* If you don't know what column to compare the year to, we can't help you there; it's up to you to understand the data you are working with. Presumably it would, however, be the `OrderDate`, no?

Comment: (You probably also don't need to join the categories at all; you know the subcat you want and you can stop at the Products table because products contains subcat)

Comment: @CaiusJard Correct sorry I didn't even see that. The results are looking way better. So now its just figuring out how to have the year as an input and show the top sales by month for the top salesman. Adding everything to the proc is not my issue just the select and display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the best performer per month.**

- To check that a date is within a particular year, instead of comapring using the `YEAR` function, it is best to calculate the beginning and end points. The end should be exclusive, this is called a *half-open interval*.
- You can also group by `EOMONTH` (end of month) which can be a little more efficient than grouping by `DATENAME(MONTH`, you can calculate the actual name afterwards.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE getTopSalesByYear (@Year int)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
  s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName AS SalesPerson,
  DATENAME(MONTH, s.SalesMonth) AS SalesMonth,
  s.TotalSales
FROM (
    SELECT
      p.FirstName,
      p.LastName,
      p.BusinessEntityID,
      EOMONTH(SOH.OrderDate) AS SalesMonth,
      SUM(SOH.SubTotal) AS TotalSales,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EOMONTH(SOH.OrderDate) ORDER BY SUM(SOH.SubTotal) DESC) AS rn
    FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
    INNER JOIN sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD ON SOH.SalesOrderId = SOD.SalesOrderId
    INNER JOIN sales.SalesPerson sp on soh.SalesPersonID = sp.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN Person.Person p on p.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN Production.Product Pr on sod.ProductID = pr.ProductID
    WHERE pr.ProductCategoryID = 2
      AND SOH.OrderDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(@Year    , 1, 1)
      AND SOH.OrderDate <  DATEFROMPARTS(@Year + 1, 1, 1)
    GROUP BY
      p.FirstName,
      p.LastName,
      p.BusinessEntityID,
      EOMONTH(SOH.OrderDate)
) s
WHERE s.rn = 1
ORDER BY SalesMonth;

GO
```

Note that this will only give you results for a month if there are actually sales in that month. If there are no sales, you will not get `0`, there will be no row for that month.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense, removed the unnecessary joins as well, I will post the complete answer just now :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the assistance, see below finished and working query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getTopSalesByYear (@Year int)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
  s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName AS SalesPerson,
  DATENAME(MONTH, s.SalesMonth) AS SalesMonth,
  s.TotalSales
FROM (
    SELECT
      p.FirstName,
      p.LastName,
      p.BusinessEntityID,
      EOMONTH(SOH.OrderDate) AS SalesMonth,
      SUM(SOH.SubTotal) AS TotalSales,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EOMONTH(SOH.OrderDate) ORDER BY SUM(SOH.SubTotal) DESC) AS rn
    FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
    INNER JOIN sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD ON SOH.SalesOrderId = SOD.SalesOrderId
    INNER JOIN sales.SalesPerson sp on soh.SalesPersonID = sp.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN Person.Person p on p.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN Production.Product Pr on sod.ProductID = pr.ProductID
    WHERE Pr.ProductSubcategoryID = 2 
      AND SOH.OrderDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(@Year    , 1, 1)
      AND SOH.OrderDate <  DATEFROMPARTS(@Year + 1, 1, 1)
    GROUP BY
      p.FirstName,
      p.LastName,
      p.BusinessEntityID,
      EOMONTH(SOH.OrderDate)
) s
WHERE s.rn = 1
ORDER BY SalesMonth;

GO

--Execute 
--Exec getTopSalesByYear 2011
```